# read angles in radian and convert them in degrees/minutes/seconds

Tags: matlab, geometry

```
n=0;
disp('This program performs an angle conversion');
disp('input data set to a straight line. Enter the name');
disp('of the file containing the input Lambda in radian:  ');
filename = input('   ','s');
[fid,msg] = fopen(filename,'rt');
if fid < 0
    disp(msg);
else
    A=textscan(fid, '%g',1);
    while ~feof(fid)
        Lambda = A(1);
        n = n + 1;
        A = textscan(fid, '%f',1);
    end
fclose(fid);    
end
Alpha=Lambda*180/pi;
fprintf('Angle converted from radian to degree/minutes/seconds:\n');
fprintf('Alpha      =%12d\n',Alpha);
fprintf('No of angles   =%12d\n',n);
```

Comment: what is this?..please format it..

Comment: I'm trying to write a program that reads angles in radian from an input file and convert them in degress/minutes/secondes. That's how far I got and did not get the right result

Answer (score 4):

To convert to from deg/min/sec to degrees you use:

```
Degree = MinutesOfArc/(60 MinutesOfArc/Degree) +
       + SecondsOfArc/(3600 SecondsOfArc/Degree)
```

For instance, 45 deg, 30 min, 30 sec = 45.508 degrees.  So you can invert that operation by doing:

```
AlphaDeg = floor(Alpha);
AlphaMinAndSec = (Alpha - AlphaDeg)*60;
AlphaMin = floor(AlphaMinAndSec);
AlphaSec = (AlphaMinAndSec - AlphaMin)*60;
```

Note that this doesn't work for negative inputs because of the `floor` operation.  It's also slower than it could be.  But in case your question is homework, I'll leave you to figure out the rest.